# Pass function as argument to a function

Tags: vba, excel

I am working with a module that involves many functions that are almost identical except for the sub function that is called within. (The arguments are the same, and the loops run the same.)

An example of such a function is the following:

```
Function Run1(lookupString) As Boolean
    For i = 1 To nA
        For j = 1 To nB
            Checkbox = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Cells(j,1)
            If Checkbox = lookupString
                RunLocation(Checkbox)
                Run1 = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    Run1 = False
End Function
```

I have other functions that are identical except for the call to "RunLocation" which is different inside the other functions. Is there a way to have just one function in this form but include the sub function that it calls as an argument?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [excel vba: Special Types - Functions as Arguments of Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118344/excel-vba-special-types-functions-as-arguments-of-functions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Function Run1(lookupString, procName As String) As Boolean
    For i = 1 To nA
        For j = 1 To nB
            CheckBox = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Cells(j, 1)
            If CheckBox = lookupString Then

                'RunLocation (CheckBox)
                Application.Run "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & _
                          "'!Module1." & subName, CheckBox
                'Adust "Module1" to whatever is the name of the
                '  code module with the methods you want to run...

                Run1 = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    Run1 = False
End Function
```

**EDIT:** use of Evaluate, and an interesting way to use a UDF to directly update a worksheet (something normally tricky to do...)

```
'************* a few test methods to call *******************
'just return the value
Function DoIt(c As Range)
    DoIt = "Value is " & c.Value
End Function

'change the value
Function DoIt2(c As Range)
    c.Value = 33
    DoIt2 = "Value is " & c.Value
End Function

'a sub instead of a function
Sub DoIt3(c1 As Range, c2 As Range)
    c1.Value = c2.Value
    c1.Interior.Color = IIf(c1.Value > 10, vbRed, vbYellow)
End Sub
'******************** end test methods ***********************

Sub Tester()
    'A1=22
    Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Evaluate("=DoIt(A1)")  '>> Value is 22
    Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Evaluate("=DoIt2(A1)") '>> Value is 33
    ActiveSheet.Evaluate "DoIt3(A1,A2)" '>> Sets A1 to A2
End Sub

'########  run as a UDF, this actually changes the sheet! ##############
' changing value in src updates dest and set interior color
Function Tester2(dest, src)

    dest.Parent.Evaluate "DoIt3(" & dest.Address(False, False) & "," _
                        & src.Address(False, False) & ")" 
    Tester2 = "Changed sheet!"

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am wondering if this can also be done by using the evaluate method? (And I assume procName and subName are meant to be the same here, is that right?)

Comment: @siddharth rout - FYI