# VBA , how to Pass function as parameter of another function

Tags: vba, function, ms-word, return

Passing function as parameter of another function

```
Sub transliterate() 
  somecode
  ...
  ...
  ...

  return word(a,b)
End Sub 

sub word(x,y)


end sub
```

Comment: Does [excel vba: Special Types - Functions as Arguments of Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118344/excel-vba-special-types-functions-as-arguments-of-functions) help?

Comment: What you're asking is not clear. Please use the [edit] link below the question to provide more information about what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Why would you not call a function direct from within another procedure/function?

Comment: Did I correctly understand your question, now?

Comment: i think yes but i am try to do something else, i am running it in Msword macros

Comment: maybe i can share my code with you, can you give feedback ?

Comment: In order to let someone know you're answering you need to use the `@` plus the name: @akaamil for example. Otherwise we won't be notified. You can share code in a question. For the stated question it doesn't matter in which application the VBA code is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA does not use `return` to pass back the result of a Function. VBA uses the following kind of construct, where the result is assigned to the function name. When `End Function` is reached the value assigned to the function's name is returned.

```
Sub testTransliterate()
  Dim a As String, b As String, Result As String

  a = "one"
  b = "two"
  Result = transliterate(x(a), b)
  Debug.Print Result
End Sub

Function x(a As String) As String
    x = a & " test"        
End Function

Function transliterate(x, y) As String
    Dim Result As String

   Result = y & ", " & x
   transliterate = Result
End Function
```