# Loop over cells and apply a function to each cell -- without repeating too much code

Tags: excel, vba, function, loops, iterator

I'm working on a project for Excel (2016 - but I can argue for the newer version) in VBA.

---

I've found this related topic here:    [excel vba: Special Types - Functions as Arguments of Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118344/excel-vba-special-types-functions-as-arguments-of-functions/13489155),    but I don't understand it well enough to implement it. And also this    here:    https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138557/functional-framework    which is currently over my head. I can work on learning these topics    if that's what it takes, but I might need someone to help explain how    they work better.

---

I have found myself constantly writing the same set of code over and over again:

```
Sub SpecificProcess()
     Dim c as Range
     Dim selectedRange as Range
     Set selectedRange = Application.Selection

     For Each c in selectedRange.Cells
          'Do some stuff to the cell
     Next c
End Sub
```

The problem is that I need to repeat that all the time:

```
Sub Add1toValue()
End Sub

Sub ChangeColorToX()
End Sub

Sub CountFingersAndToes()
End Sub

Sub Foo()
End Sub
```

and so on.  Each one of those has the common factor of: "Do something to every cell in the selection.  And the code smells really bad.  Especially if I accidentally screw up the loop a bit.

---

If It was python, I would do something like the following:

note: for a while I was really into learning python, so I have some knowledge of medium level coding practices - but I haven't used it in 15 years or so (3.1 update?), and all of those memories are locked away and VBA is a very different beast. But if someone can start explaining how something can work in VBA I can probably understand it.

```
'PseudoPython Code 
Function Looper( f as function, *args, **kwargs )
     selectedRange = Selection.range()
     
     for c in selectedRange
          f(c, *args, **kwargs)
     next c

Function f_Sample(c as cell, arg1, arg2, ... kwarg1, kwarg2)
     c.SpecificProcesses(arg_n, kwarg_n)

if __init__=="__main__"
     `select cells
     `add one to each cell, change the color, and foobar, in order
     makeSelection()
     Looper(f_addone, n_times)
     Looper(f_changeColor, "RoyGBiv")
     Looper(f_foobar, "spamspamspam")
'Note: maybe Looper would be a decorator in python?
```

and the result is that it would do those functions to each cell in the selection, iteratively, and I wouldn't have to write the looping structure over and over again.

I would even be able to extend this to make a LoopOverCells, LoopOverWorkSheets, LoopOverSpams, and so on.

---

What would be the best way to handle this in a properly coded way - but limited to the VBA / EXCEL  universe.

Comment: There's no out-of-the-box way to pass functions around in VBA: without implementing the sort of things covered in your linked posts you are dependent on using the string names of the functions together with (eg) `Evaluate` or `CallByName`

Comment: so then how would I go about doing this, I would have to make Looper a class to call the other things?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below and use `Application.Run` to call a procedure by its name. Downside of that is that you have to use a `ParamArray` to submit the arguments and you cannot specify each argument in the procedure. So you need to declare a variable for each argument you expect to ensure the correct datatype.

You might want some error handling on the parameters or not, depends on how much information you want to return or just let it run into a exception (the `CheckArguments` part is not necessarily needed but in case of `"ChangeColorToX", 1, 5` there are more arguments than needed and you might wonder why `5` does not work if it doesn't check for the arguments and errors).

```
Option Explicit
    
Public Sub Example()
    DoSomethingToEveryCellInSelection "AddXAndYtoValue", 1, 5
    
    DoSomethingToEveryCellInSelection "ChangeColorToX", RGB(255, 255, 0)

    DoSomethingToEveryCellInSelection "AddXAndYtoValue", "A", "B" ' correct amount of argument but wrong datatype
    DoSomethingToEveryCellInSelection "ChangeColorToX", 1, 5  ' wrong amount of arguments
End Sub

Public Sub DoSomethingToEveryCellInSelection(ByVal ProcedureName As String, ParamArray Args() As Variant)
    Dim c As Range
    Dim selectedRange As Range
    Set selectedRange = Application.Selection

    For Each c In selectedRange.Cells
        Application.Run ProcedureName, c, Args
    Next c
End Sub

Private Sub AddXAndYtoValue(ByVal Cell As Range, ByRef Args() As Variant)
    ' maybe some error checking for the amount of parameters
    CheckArguments "AddXAndYtoValue", 2, Args ' we expect 2 arguments
    
    ' we need to define variables for each argument to ensure that we have the correct data type
    ' if we don't do that the code might concatenate in case we submit strings as arguments
    ' in other cases other things might go wrong
    
    Dim x As Double
    x = Args(0)
    
    Dim y As Double
    y = Args(1)
    
    Cell.Value = Cell.Value + Args(0) + Args(1)
End Sub

Private Sub ChangeColorToX(ByVal Cell As Range, ByRef Args() As Variant)
    ' maybe some error checking for the amount of parameters
    CheckArguments "ChangeColorToX", 1, Args ' we expect 1 argument
    
    Dim Color As Variant
    Color = Args(0)
    
    Cell.Interior.Color = Color
End Sub

Private Sub CheckArguments(ByVal ProcedureName As String, ByVal ArgsNo As Long, ByRef Args() As Variant)
    ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/raise-method
    If UBound(Args) <> ArgsNo - 1 Then
        ' raise an error that the function needs 2 parameters
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, ProcedureName , "Wrong amount of parameters."
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Peh. Ill give it a try next week and let you know how it worked.  It's a doable solution if it works.  I was under the impression from the research I had done that I needed to implement a class or interface to do it like this.